# Inserting strings into postgresql through pyscopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert some string values into a postgresql db. namely:

```
macaddress,
timestamp (date time format)
type of device (string)
subtype (string)
```

example:

```
INSERT INTO device (address, tstamp, type, subtype) 
     VALUES ('00:00:00:00','2012-02-22 19:31:26','computer','notebook')
```

I'm using python psycopg2 script to dump the data and the following error is appearing:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO device VALUES (default, '%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
              (mac, date, typedev, subtype,))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

the command I'm using to insert is:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO device VALUES (default, '%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
              (mac, date, typedev, subtype,))
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems:

1. You don't need to quote the parameter placeholders (`%s`). The good people of psycopg2 will ensure that is done properly for you.
2. `executemany()` [expects a sequence of parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

So since you're only inserting one row you could just use `execute()`:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO device VALUES (default,%s,%s,%s,%s)", 
          (mac, date, typedev, subtype,))
```

---

When you need to use `executemany()` remember to pass it a sequence of parameters, e.g.:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO device VALUES (default,%s,%s,%s,%s)", 
              [(mac, date, typedev, subtype,),])
```