# Python MySQL Update taking 10-12 seconds to update about 1000 records

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have something along the lines of:

```
while True:
    variables are set - Each loop the variables are different.
    sql = sql statement with above variables
    send sql to MySQL server
```

I am able to update 100K records via MySQL console in a fraction of the above time. Can anyone point me in the right direction? - Thanks

Comment: Some proper code would help...but I suspect you are creating lots of update queries rather than a single call which can be optimised by the database engine.

Comment: If you haven't already looked into using the `.executemany()` method, please give that a shot. Here is an example (admittedly it's for another RDBMS, but the concept is the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622689/inserting-strings-into-postgresql-through-pyscopg2

Comment: @bernie Are you saying I should build the SQL and then send it once? Or do I add the .executemany() to the while loop?

Comment: Apologies. I had to step away. Glad you solved the problem on your own. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.executemany() worked and here is how I changed the code to have a .2-.3 second times vs 10-12 seconds:

```
while True:
    variables are set - Each loop the variables are different.         
    data = variables - adding to data on each loop

sql = sql statement + data
send sql as a batch
```

This helped a lot: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Thanks for all your help as well.